# Pandas - printing limited rows based on a value in one column

Tags: python, csv, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I wanted to limit the rows being printed by selecting rows based on a value in a specific column.

For instance:

```
Column1, Column2, Column3
aaa, bbb, ccc
none, ddd, ggg
```

I just want to print the row where `Column1` value is `none`.

Here is my code:

```
for v in df:
    if 'none' in df['2nd_prize']:
        print v
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: for v in df['2nd_prize']:
    if 'none' in df['2nd_prize']:
        print v

Comment: I recommend that you put a full example with sample input into your question, rather than adding lines in comments.

Comment: @merlin2011 I added the code.

Comment: It appears to be a whitespace issue with your parsing. I'll post an answer in a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
for row in table:
  if row[0] is none:
    print row
```

Answer (score 1):

You could subset the rows of the dataframe using [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to restrict rows containing `"none"` in `Column 1` as shown:

**Data Preparation**

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: from io import StringIO
   ...: 

In [2]: df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
   ...: '''
   ...: Column1, Column2, Column3
   ...: aaa, bbb, ccc
   ...: none, ddd, ggg
   ...: kkk, jjj, ppp
   ...: none, eee, fff
   ...: '''))
```

**Operations**

```
In [3]: df.loc[df['Column1'] == "none"]
Out[3]: 
  Column1  Column2  Column3
1    none      ddd      ggg
3    none      eee      fff
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with mask:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column2': {0: 'bbb', 1: 'ddd'}, 
                   'Column1': {0: 'aaa', 1: 'none'}, 
                   'Column3': {0: 'ccc', 1: 'ggg'}})

print (df)
  Column1 Column2 Column3
0     aaa     bbb     ccc
1    none     ddd     ggg

print (df['Column1'] == "none")
0    False
1     True
Name: Column1, dtype: bool

print (df[df['Column1'] == "none"])
  Column1 Column2 Column3
1    none     ddd     ggg
```

If values contains whitespaces in start of strings, use [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column2': {0: ' bbb', 1: ' ddd'}, 
                   'Column1': {0: ' aaa', 1: ' none'}, 
                   'Column3': {0: ' ccc', 1: ' ggg'}})

print (df)
  Column1 Column2 Column3
0     aaa     bbb     ccc
1    none     ddd     ggg

print (df['Column1'].str.strip() == "none")
0    False
1     True
Name: Column1, dtype: bool

print (df[df['Column1'].str.strip() == "none"])
  Column1 Column2 Column3
1    none     ddd     ggg
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one additional approach which first manually strips out the whitespace, and then feeds the processed file contents to pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# First strip out the whitespace
contents = open('Input.txt').read().splitlines()
contents = "\n".join([",".join([x.strip() for x in y.split(",")]) for y in contents])

# Convert to a stringIO to feed to pandas
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(unicode(contents, 'utf-8')))

print df[df['Column1'] == "none"]
```